# What is the problem with this piece of code?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am writing for deleting the last node of a doubly linked list. But, every time this function is giving me segmentation fault when I have 2 or more than 2 elements in the list.

```
void deleteEnd()
{
    struct node *ptr;
    if(head==NULL)
        printf("\nList is empty.First add some numbers");
    else if(head->next==NULL)
    {
        head = NULL;
        free(head);
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = head;   
        while(ptr->next != NULL)  
        {  
            ptr = ptr -> next;   
        }  
        ptr -> prev -> next = NULL;   
        free(ptr);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `free` on a NULL pointer is valid, but it serves absolutely no purpose at all.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That `else if` is for when you have only one node (`head`) left in the list. You `NULL`ing `head` before calling `free()` is leaking memory. More can't really be said at this point because your example is incomplete. I'd suspect the code *adding* elements to the list doesn't initialize `prev` / `next` properly, but that is guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you are deleting a node from a linked list it is a good practice to pass a reference to the first node of the list as an argument of the function. In your case you are not showing us where the head is coming from, and I think that it could be quite a useful info, and I bet that the error hides there.

That is how the implementation could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// insert end node: this is for testing purposes
struct node *insertEnd(struct node *head, int value) {
    struct node *ptr, *new_node;
    ptr = head;

    new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    // The list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new_node;
        return head;
    }
    // Non empty list
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = new_node;
    return head;
}

// delete end node
struct node *deleteEnd(struct node *head) {
    struct node *ptr, *preptr;
    ptr = head;
    preptr = NULL;
    // The list is empty
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("The list is empty. Nothing to delete.\n");
        return head;
    }
    while(ptr->next != NULL) {
        preptr = ptr;
        ptr= ptr->next;
    }
    free(ptr);
    if (preptr == NULL) {
        head = NULL;
    }
    else {
        preptr->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    struct node *llist;
    llist = NULL;

    llist = insertEnd(llist, 10);
    llist = insertEnd(llist, 20);
    llist = insertEnd(llist, 30);

    llist = deleteEnd(llist);
    llist = deleteEnd(llist);
    llist = deleteEnd(llist);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a great idea to maintain a global variable head and update it after every push/pop. See this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *start = NULL;

struct node *deleteEnd(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr = start;
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList is empty!!!");
        return start;
    }
    else if(ptr->next == NULL)
    {
        free(ptr);
        start = NULL;
        return start;        
    }
    else
    {
        while((ptr->next)->next!=NULL)      //by doing this you dont have to maintain a prev pointer
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        struct node *temp = ptr->next;
        free(temp);
        ptr->next = NULL;
        return start;
              
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!!